# What's the difference between knots and fit points?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry, spline

For the spline curve, what's the difference between knots and fit points?

I know fit points are always on the curve, what does knots used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fit points are the **input data points**.  The knots are the **limits between the various pieces of the spline**.

They can coincide, for instance when you want to [interpolate between points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29):
[image: Interpolation with a spline]

However, if you want a smooth curve that fits a noisy data curve, then you can use a spline with only a few knots (whose positions do not generally coincide with your data points):

[image: Smoothing with a spline]